# Greek small letters not showing correctly in XML nor runtime

Tags: android, xml, unicode, utf-8

I'm developing an application which involves messing around with some Greek and math characters. I have been trying for some time to render them into my XML, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, since I have used the unicode for the Strings that are looking bad, `Html.fromHtml`, `strings.xml` and even tried another font.
These are the letters that are not showing correctly: β, μ, σ and ω.
This is my XML for beta:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_beta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/special_chars_background"
                android:text="@string/beta"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="21sp" />
```

Where `@string/beta` equals to `\u03B2` and it looks like a normal capital `B`.
Can you guys please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this : <string name="beta"> &#946;</string>

Comment: Is it only in XML? Does it work when you set the string in code?

Comment: @lionscribe happens both ways.. Funny thing is that the `clickListener` of the button is set to append a String to a `TextView`, so I'm doing an append of `btn.getText` which inserts the right string...

Comment: @BapusahebShinde I tried this putting the code on the string resources, doesn't work for me unfortunately :(

Comment: @pamobo0609 its working.copy this in string.xml file.... <string name="beta">&#946;</string>

Comment: @BapusahebShinde I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work for me... I even tried with several fonts that support the characters and still nothing

Comment: i tried it for textview and its working perfectly

Comment: @BapusahebShinde could it be that I'm working with Windows? (Was not my choice, sorry)

Comment: no .thats not any issue.

Comment: Obviously it's a style value in the button that causes it. Maybe bold font, italic, or maybe fakeBold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : add android:textAllCaps="false" in Button property

```
  <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_beta"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/special_chars_background"
                        android:text="@string/beta"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="21sp" />
```

in string.xml put this string

```
<string name="beta">&#946;</string>
```